# Comparar itens de tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
Pessoa1                     Pessoa2
+----+--------+             +----+--------+
| Id |  Nome  |             | Id |  Nome  |
+----+--------+             +----+--------+
| 1  | Maria  |             | 3  | Maria  |
| 2  | João   |             | 4  | João   |
+----+--------+             | 5  | Pedro  |
                            +----+--------+
```

Gostaria de obter os nomes que aparecem nas duas tabelas.

```
Resultado
+--------+
|  Nome  |
+--------+
| Maria  |
| João   |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o ID de ambas as tabelas são iguais, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT a.Nome FROM Pessoa1 a JOIN Pessoa2 b ON a.Id = b.Id;
```

Ou trocar o Id pelo Nome, porém o resultado seria o mesmo e o ideal é utilizar sempre o identificador.

EDIT

Conforme a edição que você fez na pergunta:

```
SELECT a.Nome FROM Pessoa1 a JOIN Pessoa2 b ON a.Nome = b.Nome;
```

Comment: Pergunta editada, preciso que seja com base no nome.

Comment: Arrumado adicionando um exemplo levando em consideração o Nome.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilziar `INNER JOIN` pela coluna `Nome`

```
SELECT Pessoa1.Nome FROM Pessoa1 INNER JOIN Pessoa2 ON (Pessoa1.Nome = Pessoa2.Nome)
```

**EDIT:**

Não é ideal utilizar `INNER JOIN` sem uma coluna indexada, pode deixar a consulta muito lenta dependendo da quantidade de registro que você tem em ambas as tabelas.

Comment: Pergunta editada, preciso que seja com base no nome.

Comment: A query esta com base no nome, a única diferença é que traz o campo `Id` no resultado, apenas tire o `Pessoa1.Id` nos campos da query